# Rails 4.2.7.1 No route matches [POST] for update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button, nested-forms

Having in routes.rb

```
       resources :subjectheadings do
         get "delete"
       end
```

it will generate the following routes

```
       subjectheading_delete GET    /subjectheadings/:subjectheading_id/delete(.:format) subjectheadings#delete
             subjectheadings POST   /subjectheadings(.:format)                           subjectheadings#create
          new_subjectheading GET    /subjectheadings/new(.:format)                       subjectheadings#new
         edit_subjectheading GET    /subjectheadings/:id/edit(.:format)                  subjectheadings#edit
              subjectheading PATCH  /subjectheadings/:id(.:format)                       subjectheadings#update
                             PUT    /subjectheadings/:id(.:format)                       subjectheadings#update
                             DELETE /subjectheadings/:id(.:format)                       subjectheadings#destroy
```

Then in the in the view

```
       <%= form_for(@subjectheading, :remote => true, :url => (@subjectheading.new_record? ? subjectheadings_path : subjectheading_path(@subjectheading))) do |f| %>
```

will generate the HTML code

```
       <form class="edit_subjectheading" id="edit_subjectheading_30" action="/subjectheadings/30" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
                  ...
```

in the form @subjectheading.persisted? is true, but during **update** Rails attempts to use POST instead of PATCH

```
       ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/subjectheadings/30")
```

Any clue what's wrong here?

** Update1 **

It seems to be a conflict (or a bug) related to the **nested forms** because when they are commented out, then the PATCH method will be used:

```
 Started PATCH "/subjectheadings/30" for ... 
   Processing by SubjectheadingsController#update as JS
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?

** Update2 **

There is a radio button in the nested forms

```
  <%= f.fields_for :extsubjectheadings do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.radio_button :ext_default, ff.object.ext_default, :name => "subjectheading[extsubjectheadings_attributes][][ext_default]", :checked => ff.object.ext_default %>
```

This generated the HTML code

```
  <input name="subjectheading[extsubjectheadings_attributes][][ext_default]" type="radio" value="true" checked="checked" id="subjectheading_extsubjectheadings_attributes_1_ext_default_true">
```

This radio button makes the troubles and by summit the form uses POST, otherwise when is commented out uses PATCH as expected. What is wrong here? Is the *id* too long?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the url manually.

```
<%= form_for(@subjectheading) do %>

<% end %>
```

Rails will set the url to `subjectheadings_path` or `subjectheading_path` depending on if the record is persisted. If this does not work than you are most likely doing something very wrong in your controller or model.

Don't add `destroy` routes via GET unless absolutely necessary. As this violates the fact that GET requests should NOT have side effects.

Also when naming tables and identifiers stick to the `snake_case` scheme.

```
# inconsistent and does not work with inflection
subjectheading

# good
subject_heading
```

Comment: The form is actually correct `Rack::MethodOverride` should pickup on the `_method` param. It could be javascript related since you are using the Rails UJS `remote: true` option. Try removing it, and submitting the form. Your rails server log should read "Treating request as PATCH"